# Sync/Linking MS Access with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, synchronization

I'm trying to sync/linking Access Table with mysql using ODBC

i have a table example Person in msaccess..i link it to a mysql database also named person

After linking I got a new table in access..the field are same as in the original table..
[screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13AOE.png)

if i made an update in the person1 table it is updated in the person table in mysql.... meanwhile if i update Person table is not updating in mysql or in the Person1 table..now i have two tables in access

How do i prevent using the new table (Person1) and instead use the original Table to link in to a mysql table ?

Comment: Just remove the person table from ms access and rename the person1 to person in ms access and keep using that.

Comment: Yes that works..Thank you...

Comment: by the way is this normal ? access creating a duplicate table ?

Comment: You cannot link an existing table to a remote table. When you link to a remote table that always creates a new table in access. This is the expected behaviour, since the linked tables behave differently from the native ones.

Comment: Ok thanks again for the explanation

Comment: @Shadow you told the man to remove a local table without backing it up! :D